# "gap_init:2" popup when launching Ripple through Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

When launching a Cordova app through Visual Studio I get a popup saying:

> gap_init:2

Pressing OK results in another popup:

> gap:[null,"App","show","`App1124019580`"]

After pressing OK to more popups (seemingly related to the loaded plugins), the JavaScript console in Visual Studio is printing the following in an infinite loop while Chrome and Visual Studio hangs:

> processMessage failed: invalid message: ""

The only way to proceed is to kill Chrome and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is seen when having the Ripple extension installed in Chrome while trying to launch an app with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova.

Disabling the Ripple extension in Chrome results in launch from Visual Studio working again.